# Enabling an ethernet port on an H3C S5820X-28S switch

Tags: switch, hp

I'm working on a client's H3C S5820X-28S switch. I'm thoroughly unfamiliar with H3C (which, as I understand, is just an pre-buyout HP switch) having only touched Cisco and some Juniper switches.

Anywho, I have a 10Gig port That appears to be configured, but refuses to turn on for some reason. It's in a remote datacenter and I have eyes on the switch that say that we have it patched properly, but not getting link. I've managed to pull up its current config and this is what it's set to:

```
 [conf]display interface Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/14
 Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/14 current state: DOWN
 IP Packet Frame Type: PKTFMT_ETHNT_2, Hardware Address: 3822-d6e5-3763
 Description: Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/14 Interface
 Loopback is not set
 Media type is stack wire,Port hardware type is STACK_SFP_PLUS
 10Gbps-speed mode, full-duplex mode
 Link speed type is force link, link duplex type is force link
 Flow-control is not enabled
 The Maximum Frame Length is 10000
 Broadcast MAX-ratio: 100%
 Unicast MAX-ratio: 100%
 Multicast MAX-ratio: 100%
 Allow jumbo frame to pass
 PVID: 101
 Link delay is 0(sec)
 Port link-type: access
 Tagged   VLAN ID : none
 Untagged VLAN ID : 101
 Port priority: 0
 Peak value of input: 0 bytes/sec, at 2003-08-06 09:46:13
 Peak value of output: 0 bytes/sec, at 2003-08-06 09:46:13
 Last 300 seconds input:  0 packets/sec 0 bytes/sec 0%
 Last 300 seconds output:  0 packets/sec 0 bytes/sec 0%
 Input (total):  0 packets, 0 bytes
         0 unicasts, 0 broadcasts, 0 multicasts, 0 pauses
 Input (normal):  0 packets, - bytes
         0 unicasts, 0 broadcasts, 0 multicasts, 0 pauses
 Input:  0 input errors, 0 runts, 0 giants, 0 throttles
         0 CRC, 0 frame, - overruns, 0 aborts
         - ignored, - parity errors
 Output (total): 0 packets, 0 bytes
         0 unicasts, 0 broadcasts, 0 multicasts, 0 pauses
 Output (normal): 0 packets, - bytes
         0 unicasts, 0 broadcasts, 0 multicasts, 0 pauses
 Output: 0 output errors, - underruns, - buffer failures
         0 aborts, 0 deferred, 0 collisions, 0 late collisions
         0 lost carrier, - no carrier
```

I've manually enabled/disabled the port with `shutdown/undo shutdown` but still cannot get it working. Is there something that I may have missed in the config?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
Media type is stack wire,Port hardware type is STACK_SFP_PLUS
```

You haven't said what's being connected to the port, or if there are any syslog errors (presumably of an "unsupported" SFP) Run "`display transceiver interface`" to see what it thinks about the module(s).  Your output shows a direct-attach cable is plugged in.

Comment: `[conf-Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/14]display transceiver interface`
    `Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/14 transceiver information:`
      `Transceiver Type              : STACK_SFP_PLUS`
      `Connector Type                : COPPER`
      `Wavelength(nm)                : N/A`
      `Transfer Distance(m)          : 3(TP)`
      `Digital Diagnostic Monitoring : NO`
      `Vendor Name                   : H3C`

Ugh... can't get the formatting right. Anyways, this is the output.

Comment: Found a syslog entry as well
`OPTMOD Warning MODULE_IN Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/14: The transceiver is STACK_SFP_PLUS.`

Comment: (formatting in comments is limited. you can add additional info by editing your original question)

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old post, but the issue turned out to be a bad tranceiver. Ordered a new one and everything was up and running just fine.